# apply color saturation on the entire renderer

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, effect, spritebatch

I would like to apply a color saturation on the entire final renderer.

Is there an easy way to do it without using shaders ?
I don't know anything about DirectX :x

I saw an "Effect" parameter in spriteBatch.Begin() but i didn't find any tutorial about it :s

Hope you can guide me.

Comment: An `Effect` is a shader.

Comment: @andrew Q1: Is shader means "Effect with DirectX" ? Q2: So, for this basic effect, I have to code it with DirectX ? :( *scared*

Comment: Shader code is written in HLSL. It's not too hard. You don't need to mess about with DirectX. Check out this sample: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a shader to this. A shader is an `Effect`.

You can create a new effect by right clicking a content project, clicking "Add New Item", and selecting a "Effect" file. The resulting `.fx` file is in the HLSL language. It will be compiled by the content pipeline, and you an load it with:

```
Effect myEffect = Content.Load<Effect>("myEffect");
```

There is an [official example of how to use effects with `SpriteBatch` here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_effects) (if you want **de**saturation, there's an example in there). And [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) may also be useful.

I won't reproduce the code for a saturation effect here, but you can find several examples via Google. [Here is one example on the GameDev site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28782/hue-saturation-brightness-contrast-effect-in-hlsl).

Comment: i modified the shader sample to follow my code logic. (Indeed, as you said, it's not too hard) It works. as usual, thx a lot Andrew.